# Dropping columns with duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2415 columns and I want to drop consecutive duplicate columns. That is, if column 1 and column 2 have the same values, I want to drop column 2.

I wrote the below code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
for i in (0,len(df.columns)-1):
    if (df[i].tolist() == df[i+1].tolist()):
        df=df.drop([i+1], axis=1)
    else:
        df=df
```

Comment: If the col1 is duplicate with col10, will you drop col10 ?

Comment: @BEN_YO No, I will drop column 10 only if it is the same as column 9

Comment: ok updated ~ :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select column name from the index.Try this.

```
columns = df.columns
drops = []
for i in (0,len(df.columns)-1):
    if (df[columns[i]].tolist() == df[columns[i+1]].tolist()):
        drops.append(columns[i])
df = df.drop(drops,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `shift`

```
df.loc[:,~df.eq(df.astype(object).shift(axis=1)).all()]
```

Comment: If your `df` has 1 million rows..do you think `transpose` of df is a better solution!. Also he wants to remove consecutive duplicate columns not all duplicate columns.

Comment: Perfect! Innovative solution.